# Voice Recognition in IBM Worklight for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst, voice-recognition

I'm currently writing a hybrid mobile app for iOS and Android using IBM Worklight. I want to add a voice recognition feature to the app but have struggled to find a cordova plugin implementation that works accurately. Currently I have tried the following...

- Web Speech API using a JavaScript interface. This hasn't worked because it is not supported in iOS yet.
- iSpeech. Using a cordova plugin, I have this working but the iSpeech recognition is so bad it's unusable.

If anyone has any suggestions of plugins to try or free recognition services that would work well that would be great. Better still if anyone has successfully implemented voice recognition in Cordova or Worklight on iOS I'd love to know how you achieved it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implementing it in Worklight would mean a Cordova plug-in essentially, so asking for it in Worklight specifically shouldn't be the focus, IMO. Get it working in Cordova, then "port" it.

Comment: Fair comment, I'll rephrase the question

Comment: I created the iSpeech plugin and worked fine for me

Comment: @jcesar the plugin is great, its the only thing I've got to work properly so far, it's just that the recognition often returns no confidence, or the returned text is not what was said. I'm using English_GB with a confidence error level of 0.2 but everything else is implemented as in your example app. Could I be missing something that would improve the recognition?

Comment: I have not used it on real project, but my tests at home returned the right word most of times (with no noise around)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who commented on my question. I have found a work around to my problem that may be useful to some of you. I adjusted my code to use html text inputs, when a user taps the text input to bring up the iOS keyboard they can use the built in voice recognition to add text to the input. See below:

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Ask Watson" />
```

I know this is not a perfect solution but it solved my problem in the specific app I am working on.